# text entered in uppercase during login still gives successful login

Tags: c#, sql

I have a login page for my windows application in c#.even if i enter the username and password in uppercase i.e with CAPS ON still the login is successful.

This should not be the case, as the enteries in the database are in lower case.

```
public partial class frmlogin : Form
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=TH07L019;Initial Catalog=procurement;Integrated Security=True");
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter();


    public frmlogin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Connection = con;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from login where username='" + txtusername.Text + "' and password='" + txtpassword.Text + "'";
        adp.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adp.Fill(dt);
        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            frmmain main = new frmmain();
            main.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter correct name and passowrd", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtusername.Clear();
            txtpassword.Clear();
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}
```

how to solve this problem

Comment: Reminds me of http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely a database issue - the default [collation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms143726.aspx#Collation_Defn) is probably case insensitive, meaning that any string comparisons in the database will be case insensitive.

You need to change the collation of these fields to be case sensitive, or add a hint on the username/password check query to use such a collation.

Note:

There are several issues with your code and implementation - one is that it is open to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) - you shouldn't concatenate strings into SQL like that, but use [parameterized queries](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html).

Additionally, storing passwords in plain text is highly insecure - if your database falls into malicious hands, they will have all the passwords. You should be using hashes. I suggest reading [Everything you ever wanted to know about building a secure password reset feature](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html) by Troy Hunt.

Comment: i am still a rookie to these all concepts. trying to learn and build an application. so wht do you suggest should i do if storing the password in plain text is wrong.

Comment: @Kaushik27 - Read the linked article.

Answer (score 2):

Leaving aside the fact that storing passwords in plain text is the worst idea ever from the security standpoint, and the fact that users can execute a SQL injection attack on your database by entering a "special" password<sup>+</sup>, the reason your code ignores caps is that your RDBMS has case-insensitive string comparison.

---

<sup>+</sup> *Imagine* (do not *try*) a password string that looks like this:

```
';drop table login--
```

Do you know [what would happen](http://xkcd.com/327/)? In addition,

```
';select 1;--
```

would become your "master password", letting anyone login as anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

You should either change the default collation to Case Sensitive in the Database or you can change the collation right in the query itself. like:

```
select * from login where username = 'someusername' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS 
and password = 'somepassword' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS
```